# sql query to get the latest message sent

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a chat sql table with the structure as following :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chat`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `idsender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sentTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `idreceiver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

how to get the latest message sent to the user with the id = 2 from every user he has talked with (where the idreceiver = 2) ?

this is my try , it's getting me a message from every user the user with the id = 2 has talked with  but it's not the last message :

```
SELECT * FROM chat 
WHERE idreceiver = 2 
GROUP BY idsender 
ORDER BY sentTime DESC
```

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` after `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT c.* FROM chat c 
WHERE c.idreceiver = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM chat
  WHERE idreceiver = c.idreceiver AND idsender = c.idsender AND sentTime > c.sentTime
)
```

Or `group by idsender` and join to the table:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM chat c INNER JOIN (
  SELECT idsender, MAX(sentTime) sentTime 
  FROM chat
  WHERE idreceiver = 2
  GROUP BY idsender 
) t ON t.idsender = c.idsender AND t.sentTime = c.sentTime 
WHERE c.idreceiver = 2
```

Comment: thank you @forpas, for your answer , but i did not meant the latest message he has received , i meant the latest message he has received from every user he has talked with , excuse me for the missunderstanding .

Comment: This is what the code does. Did you try it?

Comment: your answer is verified and working , thank you @forpas :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    chat

WHERE
    idreceiver = 2
    AND
    sentTime = (SELECT MAX(sentTime) FROM chat WHERE idreceiver = 2)
```

Comment: thank you @Jerry M, for your answer , but i did not meant the latest message he has received , i meant the latest message he has received from every user he has talked with , excuse me for the missunderstanding .